# How to list a string created in my MainActivity.java in my strings.xml file

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, string

I have created a `string` in my `main.java` file as follows:

```
String message = "Current Location \nLongitude: "+ location.getLongitude()+"\nLatitude: "+ location.getLatitude();
```

I want to place this string in my `strings.xml` file.

This way I can display the value of the `string` at various places in my application.

I am not sure how to do this.

Any advice?

Comment: You cannot add items to your `strings.xml` (or anything else in the `res\` folder) at runtime. If you want to store your string you'll have to do it in SharedPreferences, a Database, or in a File in internal/external storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit your strings.xml only manually, not proramatically. If this is a dynamic string (and I assume it is), you will have to save it in a static variable for example, but can't write it into strings.xml.